# How do I get gas used by or price of a single mined transaction like in etherscan through a ethereum node?

Tags: web3js, etherscan, ethers.js

I was using ethers.js to get the transaction receipt of a mined transaction but when I get the cumulative gas used it seems to give me cumulative gas of the block mined and not the transaction itself.
How do I get gas used only by a mined transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `gasUsed` parameter of the transaction receipt (https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/v3.0/html/api-providers.html#transactionreceipt) which returns the amount of gas used by the transaction.